# Comparing two list with greater than > or less than <

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have two lists that I am trying to compare with < or > in python.

One (list1) is a slope and then a horizontal line (picture a obtuse angle of around 130 degrees) the second is a linear function with a negative slope that I calculated from the first list (list2). What I would like to do is compare the two lists `list1` and `list2` and create a new `list3` where `list3` = all the points in `list1`>`list2`. I am having trouble determining how to approach this. I have attempted list comprehension but I get the error

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.

```
v = [c for c in f if c > y]
list1= [0.0, 0.36, 0.34, 0.32, 0.32, 0.3, 0.3, 0.28, 0.28, 0.26, 0.26, 0.24, 0.24, 0.22, 0.22, 0.2, 0.2, 0.18, 0.18, 0.16, 0.16, 0.14, 0.14, 0.12, 0.12, 0.1, 0.1, 0.08, 0.08, 0.06, 0.06, 0.04, 0.04, 0.02, 0.02, 0.0,..., 0.0]
list2= [ 0.36  0.35  0.34 ..., -9.62 -9.63 -9.64]
```

Any help, advice, or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Also please let me know if my question is unclear in anyway.

Comment: What is y?  Is it a list or a point?  If it's a list, are you looking for points that are greater than a given point in y, greater than all points in y, or greater than any point in y?  I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do myself.

Comment: You say "list3= all the points in list1>list2" - therein lies your ambiguity - how can a point (one of "all the points in list1") compare to a list ("list2")?

Do you mean "than the greatest value in list2"?

Comment: @ChadMiller y and f are my lists. I am looking for all points in f(list1) that are greater than y(list2). Does this help..I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @geop_sed: Okay, to clear things up, let's say list1 is `[5, 3, 4]` and list2 is `[4, 3.5, 3]`. Then should list3 be `[5, 4]`?

Comment: there is *no* mention of what f and y might be in your example. I think we all assumed them to be elements from list1 and list2. If they aren't, please tell us what they are

Comment: @Nicolas78 Thanks for the help, those f and y are the names of my lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean that `list3` is the collection of values from `list1` where the **corresponding value** in `list2` is smaller, then:

```
list3 = [item1 for item1, item2 in zip(list1, list2) if item1 > item2]
```

Comment: like this better than mine because we don't need to do the lookup twice of listx[i] (on the other hand, I'm not sure how expensive zip is)

Comment: @Nicolas78: I find `zip` to be "Pythonic". It's nice-looking, feels natural once you understand how it works, and it works well. Only when it is known that this method is too slow would I look for a different approach.

Comment: @voithos and izip it is even more ;) (at least on python 2.x)

Comment: @voithos The result here seems off(due to my lack of clarity in what I want to accomplish) in the two arrays(@DSM) that I gave. I am, maybe incorrectly, thinking of these arrays as functions say f(x)=0 and y(x)=-1/2x+b so I want all points in a new array where f(x)>y(x)..Does this make more sense?

Comment: @geop_sed: How are you thinking of arrays as functions? What is 'x' in the equations that you gave? Are you using the array indices as 'x'? It'd be nice if you gave a quick example of a simple list1, list2, and list3 (or f, y, and v, as you have it).

Comment: @voithos Thanks again for the help. What I would like to do is compare each entry in one list1 to each entry in list2 (they are both the same size) if the entry in list 1 is larger then I would like to save it to another array. I think this is the best way to articulate what I am trying to do. When I run the code that you gave I should get all zeros as a result (with the lists given above) but I do not.

Comment: the second element of your list1 is bigger than the second element of list2, so how should you get all zeroes?

Comment: @geop_sed: The second item of list1 that you gave is 0.36. The second item of list2 is 0.35. 0.36 > 0.35, so 0.36 would be saved in list3.

Comment: @voithos That is correct and a oversight on my part...but other then that the rest of the values should be zeros and when I run this code I get: [0.36, 0.28, 0.26, 0.24, 0.22, 0.2, 0.18, 0.16, 0.14, 0.12, 0.1, 0.08, 0.06, 0.04, 0.02, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...0.0]

Comment: @geop_sed: I suspect that your list1 has some incorrect values near the beginning. For example, if the `0.34` part gets repeated just like all of the other values, then the resulting list would be like what you posted.

Comment: @voithos Thanks for all the help. I realize that my list is shifted because the first entry represents time and the following entries are heights on a for that time surface. Since it was shifted and not a one to one comparison like I wanted it was giving me the incorrect values(or the correct values really just not want I wanted) sorry about the confusion and the time it took. As a last thing do you know of a quick way to exclude the first value in one of my lists?

Comment: @geop_sed: Sure, to do that just use range literals, like so: `list1[1:]`. Here the number 1 indicates the **second** item (Python is indexed from 0) and the colon indicates 'through'. Since we leave out the ending index, Python assumes that we want it through the end of the list. Thus, it'll return the list without the first item in it, but it won't modify the list directly. Instead, you can use it in the `zip()` function, like: `zip(list1[1:], list2)`

Answer (score 2):

You say "list", but from the error message and the outputs I suspect you're working with numpy arrays.  In any case, the problem with `v = [c for c in f if c > y]` is that you're comparing an element c with the array y.  You want to compare element to element.

In the case of a list, you can do the following:

```
>>> aa = [2,3,4,5]
>>> bb = [3,4,2,5]
>>> 
>>> z = [a for a,b in zip(aa,bb) if a > b]
>>> z
[4]
```

Or if you're really working with numpy arrays, you can make it even easier:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> aa = numpy.array([2,3,4,5])
>>> bb = numpy.array([3,4,2,5])
>>> aa > bb
array([False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> aa[aa > bb]
array([4])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[elmt1 for elmt1, elmt2 in zip(list1, list2) if elmt1 > elmt2]
```

This essentially directly mirrors the question: select elements from list1 that are larger than the corresponding element in list2.

If one of the lists is longer, its extra elements cannot be compared to elements from the other list, and they are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

assuming both lists are of equal size,

```
list3 = [list1[i] for i in range(len(list1)) if list1[i]>list2[i]]
```

Comment: There is really no need to use an index and get a specific element from 3 lists for each index value.

Comment: I'd never downvote a working solution in any but the most crass style or runtime complexity violations but well

Comment: I meant no offense. :)  It's true that it's mostly a matter of style; I don't want to encourage people to write C-inspired code in Python when there is a simple and usual Python syntax for it, especially when the code is suboptimal because of this. Agreed, speed does not matter too much, here, but it may matter in other circumstances; however, I do believe that style does matter, because of legibility (and ease of maintainance, etc.)

Comment: no problem. Have to admit not propagating C-style Python is a valid point, in fact. Not sure about speed though, would be interesting; zip creates a copy of the data and thus needs to allocate memory whereas looping over the list works in-place.

Comment: Thank you for your understanding.  As for the speed, with Python 2, your solution is indeed about 15% faster than the zip() solution, on 10k elements; with Python 3, it is twice as *slow*, probably because zip() returns an iterator (no in-memory zipped list), in Python 3.

Comment: I updated your solution, which was syntactically incorrect (was `… if… for` instead of `… for… if`).

Answer (score 0):

using izip_longest 
http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest

```
list3 = [i for i,j in itertools.izip_longest(list1, list2, 0) if i > j]
```

Comment: Why complete the shorter list with zeroes?  This does not appear to be mentioned in the question.

Comment: @EOL as documented izip_longest use filling for shorted iterables, it is supposed to be there as an example :) maybe a random number helps better ?

Comment: Bargubli: I'm not sure I follow you: no number can do, as I understand the question.  I understand that potential additional terms should simply not be considered.

Comment: didn't know izip. seems like the perfect mix between pythonic-ness ;) and not wasting memory :)

Comment: @EOL the filler is optional and is there as a reminder, question does not state explicitly that lists have the same lenght neither what to do in that case (that's why I though about izip_longest).

Comment: @Tomasso Bargubli: … which is why `izip()` was probably more appropriate than filling with an arbitrary number which is not mentioned in the question (as is done in the accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I correctly understand your question to mean a list of the points (x,y) at which list1[i] > list2[i] rather than just a list of values from list1, this

```
list3 = [(i,val) for i, val in enumerate(list1) if val > list2[i]]
```

will return that list as points. If you need to know at which index list1 > list2 then `enumerate` is helpful.

If all you are interested in is the list of indexes at which the two arrays are equal: all x for which f(x) > g(x) in other words, then all you need are the indexes:

```
list3 = [i for i, val in enumerate(list1) if val > list2[i]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who want a lazy iterator approach:

```
from itertools import izip, ifilter
i = ifilter(lambda (x,y): x > y, izip(list1, list2))
list3 = list(i)
```

This will quit once either list runs out of values. To iterate over the longest list, use `izip_longest`:

```
from itertools import izip_longest, ifilter
i = ifilter(lambda (x,y): x > y, izip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue=0))
list3 = list(i)
```

And since this uses iterators, you can replace `list3 = list(i)` bit with a loop to actually use the values as they get generated, if necessary.